# Is it possible to create a VPN client connect using only the terminial?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 server (VM) and would like to setup a VPN client (openvpn) using the terminal only with my VPN provider if that's possible.

I've done this before using lubuntu (12.04) and the GUI but would like to move away from GUI's if its possible.

Comment: Sure, you just set up the config file, and the cpmmand is `openvpn configfile`. If you have more detailed question edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible by the following way:
1- open you terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

2- download openvpn config file (*.ovpn) there is many websites for that.
3- run terminal and `cd` to the place were the openvpn file is downloaded to.
4- type the following:

```
sudo openvpn --config filename.ovpn
```

PS: sudo in the last command is so important.
Enjoy!!!